# Do i need to dispose variable nested a routine?

Tags: c#

I am using about 20 variables which they are created inside a void. So my question is do i need to dispose them after my void will be finish? Or gc will do this automatically?
Also should i create them inside void Title or Inside my brackets?

Example:

```
public static void MainGridControl(
       string txtComments = "",
       int InventoryItemID = 0,
       int Situation = 0,

       decimal InventoryRetailPrice = 0,
       decimal QuantityValue = 1,
       decimal ExtrasPrice = 0,
       decimal RealPrice = 0,
       decimal DiscountPrice = 0,


       string InventoryMainGroupItemCode = "",
       string MainGroupItemName = "",
       string InventoryMainGroupItemID = "",
       string InventoryName = "",
       string VatValue = "",
       string Code = "",
       string Extras = "",
       string ExtraItemsNames = "[]",
       string ExtrasComments = "",
       string Cultery = "",
       string InfoText = "",

       bool Weight = false,
       bool FreePrice = false

       )
    {

    }
```

Example 2

```
public static void MainGridControl()
    {
          string txtComments = "";
       int InventoryItemID = 0;
       int Situation = 0;

       decimal InventoryRetailPrice = 0;
       decimal QuantityValue = 1;
       decimal ExtrasPrice = 0;
       decimal RealPrice = 0;
       decimal DiscountPrice = 0;


       string InventoryMainGroupItemCode = "";
       string MainGroupItemName = "";
       string InventoryMainGroupItemID = "";
       string InventoryName = "";
       string VatValue = "";
       string Code = "";
       string Extras = "",
       string ExtraItemsNames = "[]";
       string ExtrasComments = "";
       string Cultery = "";
       string InfoText = "";

       bool Weight = false;
       bool FreePrice = false;
    }
```

All my variables are just only string, int, decimals and bool.
Is there any better way which i can handle them?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? The two examples do very different things. Example 1 shows a method with many parameters, whereas example 2 shows a method with no parameters. Which method do you want?

Comment: In first method i dont't pass any parameters. I just use them inside my void. Alsoin second method do i need to dispose them?

Comment: if you create variables inside within the scope of a method (function) they are called local variables and get created on the stack; you don't need to explicitly dispose of them, they'll get disposed when the method goes out of scope.  

I assume that you don't actually want to pass these values to the method when calling the method, so I would say use Example 2.  The GC doesn't even get involved here.

Comment: If you don't intend on passing any parameters, then don't declare any (even if they are optional parameters), and no you don't need to dispose anything. The only things you need to dispose are the ones that implements `IDisposable`. C# has a garbage collector to collect most objects.

Comment: Here's a very detailed explanation of how variables are managed in C# https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/C-Sharp-heaping-vs-stacking-in-net-part-i/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!. Please someone write it as answer, for marking it.

Comment: Note that if your method were to create object(s) implementing the `IDisposable` interface such objects should be disposed right at the time when your program is finished with using them. In other words, whether you need/should dispose variables -- or more specifically dispose the _variable content_ -- thus depends on the very nature of the content of a variable. Now, in the code snippet in your question, none of the variables is of a type that could contain a reference of an `IDisposable` object, thus disposing anything here is not necessary/possible anyway...

Comment: Depending on how many of these objects you will create, you can optimise performances converting them from class to struct, take a look here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/difference-between-struct-and-class-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases those variables will be destroyed when the method execution terminate, since their [scope](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/) is at method level.

Going further you're doing different things in the two examples. In the first one, you're creating the variables directly in the body of the method, while in the second one you're passing them as optional parameters with a default value.

This means that although both situations will dispose the variables in the end of the method, you can pass the value for some of them in the second situation.

For your situation you're using primitive types, so the garbage collector wouldn't have any problem destroying them.

However, as pointed out by @Sweeper, if you find yourself in a situation where you're using objects that implement the `IDisposable` interface, you'll have to dispose them before exiting the method via the `dispose()` method. If you don't, you'll destroy the object but you might leave undisposed resources, and this could lead to a memory leak.